# Mac OS X Lion: every time I shutdown or restart my lap...chrome and textmate open?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, boot

Every time I turn on or restart Mac OS X Lion...chrome and textmate open. Even if I uncheck "Reopen windows when logging back in" before shutdown or restart. Chrome and textmate do not appear on loggin items on Users & Groups from System Preferences so I can't  uncheck them. Is very weird and I don't really know what to do. Some good ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Check if anything about Chrome or Textmate appear in `~/Library/Saved Application State`. Note that `~/Library` is not visible by default in Finder, so in Finder choose `Go`, the `Go to folder` and paste that folder path. If these appear, delete them (make sure that you don't have Chrome or Textmate open at this point) and see if they show up after restart.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it didn't work. I close both apps and then delete the folders of chrome and textmate at Saved Application State, I restart and both apps open and those folders show up again.